# keycloak publicClient authentication in react throws error saying: Failed to initialize adapter: 'Keycloak' instance can only be initialized once

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, keycloak

I am trying to integrate keycloak publicClient authentication in react, but it throws an err saying :
Failed to initialize adapter: Error: A 'Keycloak' instance can only be initialized once.

where am i initializing twice ?

when i remove this < ReactKeycloakProvider authClient={keycloak}> the error goes away and gets user successfully authenticated, but then i dont have keycloak passed to other components of application... thanks in advance

dependencies: keycloak-js, @react-keycloak/web and js-sha256

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { HomePage } from './layouts/homePage/HomePage';
import React, { useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';  
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js';
import initOptions from './config/keyCloak';
import { ReactKeycloakProvider } from '@react-keycloak/web';

function App() {
  const keycloak = useMemo(() => {
    return new Keycloak(initOptions);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUserDetails = async () => {
      try {
        const authenticated = await keycloak.init({
          KeycloakResponseType: 'code',
          redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/',
          checkLoginIframe: false,
          pkceMethod: 'S256',
          onLoad: initOptions.onLoad,
        });

        console.log(
          `User is ${authenticated ? 'authenticated' : 'not authenticated'}`
        );
        console.log(keycloak.token);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to initialize adapter:', error);
      }
    };
    getUserDetails();
  }, [keycloak]);

  return (
    <ReactKeycloakProvider authClient={keycloak}>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage />} />             
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </ReactKeycloakProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. If you create your app using create-react-app just remove <React.StrictMode></React.StrictMode> which wraps  from index.js

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I created app using create-react-app  and removed StrictMode but the error remains the same.

Comment: For me removing React.StrictMode solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

As per the error, you can only initialize the Keycloak instance once. Strict mode makes `useEffect()` run twice, so your keycloak instance is initializing again after the first time. This doesn't mean disabling strict mode fixes your issue. Any issue caused by strict mode should be an indicator that your code has some bugs. Even if we disable strict mode, the user might re-visit the main page and `useEffect()` will run again to initialize the keycloak instance once more, causing the same error.

You can have some flag as state set to false and set it to `true` after running `keycloak.init()` and adding an if condition to only run it when it's false inside `useEffect()`.

```
function App() {
  const [kcInitialized, setKcInitialized] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const getUserDetails = async () => {
      //other code
      if (!kcInitialized){
        await keycloak.init(initObject);
        setKcInitialized(true);
      }
    };
    getUserDetails();
  },[])
}
```